# Excel VBA code completely removed after opening the sheet on other machine

Tags: excel, vba, windows, macos

I have an Excel sheet using some VBA automations. The sheet was both designed and coded using macOS Excel. Everything is working just fine **unless someone using a Windows machine opens the sheet**. This is how it acts:

- opening the sheet on any macOS machine => works as supposed to
- closing the sheet on any macOS machine & re-opening again using any macOS machine => works as supposed to
- opening the sheet on any Windows machine => works as supposed to
- closing the sheet on any Windows machine & re-opening again using any Windows machine => works as supposed to

**now the problematic cases:**

- closing the sheet on any Windows machine & re-opening again using any macOS machine => **VBA project is removed after Excel trying to get repared**
- simultaneously opened shared Excel on any Windows machine and any macOS machine => everything works as supposed until closing the file => **when re-opening on macOS, it's corrupted, BUT on a Windows machine it works as supposed to and no errors**
- **even sole opening and saving&closing using Windows machine gets the sheet corrupted** (so when trying to open on macOS it needs to be repaired and deletes the VBA code completely)

**as for steps, I've already tried:**

- I've reinstalled both macOS and Windows machines, both OS and Office 365 apps and it did not help
- instead of using .xlsm file I tried .xlsb and it did not help
- I've tried to compile the VBA project to see some potential issues and there's none
- I've password-protected the VBA (I've seen some threads regarding virus scanning) and did not help
- I've tried to (please don't laugh, I'm really desperate) ask ChatGPT for checking the code and even the AI told me my code was okay

**possible issues?**

- for MsgBox I'm using strings containing some special characters (ě, š, č, ř, ž etc.) – is this an issue? if so, why the VBA remains functional on Windows and being removed on macOS?
- VBA automation creates new sheets and names them based on input provided – could special characters be an issue?
- maybe it has something to do with saving procedure? I suspect that as soon as the sheet is saved using any Windows machine, it gets corrupted for macOS users

One of my subs here and I can share the file itself, if needed:

```
Sub vypln_dashboard()

Dim bunka_status, status
bunka_status = "B9"
status = Application.Range(bunka_status).Value

If status = "setup" Then

    Application.Range(bunka_status).Value = "done"
    Exit Sub

End If

Dim plan_list, bunka_pocet_prazdnych_balvanu, quarter, year, plan_listname, pocet_prazdnych_balvanu_plan
    plan_list = Application.Range("listname_balvany").Value
    quarter = Application.Range("B5").Value
    year = Application.Range("B6").Value
    plan_listname = plan_list & " " & quarter & "Q" & year
    bunka_pocet_prazdnych_balvanu = "B8"
    pocet_prazdnych_balvanu_plan = Application.Range(bunka_pocet_prazdnych_balvanu).Value

    Dim pole_nazvu_plan, pole_nazvu_dashboard
    pole_nazvu_plan = Application.Range("plan_pole_nazvu_balvanu").Value
    pole_nazvu_dashboard = Application.Range("pole_nazvu_balvanu_dashboard").Value

    Dim list_plan, list_dashboard As Worksheet
    Set list_plan = Worksheets(plan_listname)
    Set list_dashboard = ActiveSheet

    Dim pocet_balvanu_plan
    pocet_balvanu_plan = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(list_plan.Range(pole_nazvu_plan))
    
    Dim clovek, jmena_lidi As Range
    Set jmena_lidi = Range("lidi")
    
    Dim startovaci_bunka_nazvu_balvanu_dashboard, cilova_adresa_jmena_cloveka
    startovaci_bunka_nazvu_balvanu_dashboard = Application.Range("startovaci_bunka_nazvu_balvanu_dashboard").Value
    
    Dim offset_radku, offset_sloupcu As Integer
    offset_radku = 0
    offset_sloupcu = 4

    If pocet_balvanu_plan <> pocet_prazdnych_balvanu_plan Then

            Call update_decision
            
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect
            
            For Each clovek In jmena_lidi
    
                cilova_adresa_jmena_cloveka = Range(startovaci_bunka_nazvu_balvanu_dashboard).offset(offset_radku, offset_sloupcu).Address
                Range(cilova_adresa_jmena_cloveka) = clovek
                offset_radku = offset_radku + 10
    
            Next clovek

            Dim adresa
            adresa = Application.Range("pole_nazvu_balvanu_dashboard").Value

            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = Application.Range(adresa)

            For Each radek In rng

                If radek = "" Then

                    radek.EntireRow.Hidden = True

                Else

                    radek.EntireRow.Hidden = False

                End If

            Next radek
            
            adresa = Application.Range("dashboard_radky_navic").Value
            
            Dim nadbytecne_radky As Range
            Set nadbytecne_radky = Application.Range(adresa)

            nadbytecne_radky.EntireRow.Hidden = True

            Range(bunka_pocet_prazdnych_balvanu).Value = pocet_balvanu_plan

            ActiveSheet.Protect

            Dim reply As Integer
            reply = MsgBox("Věř nebo ne, právě jsi ušetřil spoustu času :)", , "Aktualizace dokončena")

    Else

        Exit Sub

    End If

End Sub
```

I must somehow get this particular Excel functional including the VBA automations and I run out of ideas on how to fix it :(